# Visual Studio 2015 does not refresh changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, iis, visual-studio-2015

Currently I'm playing a little bit with MVC application. But there is one thing that is very annoying. When I change something in my code (controller, view or whatever) the changes sometimes does not refresh. I see the old content. And there is more. Sometimes browser says "Waiting for localhost..." and it's waiting forever. When this happens the only thing that helps is to stop IIS and restart Visual Studio. What seems to be the problem? How can I make this work and see my changes every time I build and refresh the page? (Ctrl+F5 does not work)
I'm using Visual Studio 2015, IIS Express and Firefox (but this also happens on IE).

Comment: are you using latest updates ?

Comment: Latest updates of what? Visual Studio? Update 2 is still waiting. Do you think it will help?

Comment: Yes,I'm working with the Update 2 and no problem.

Comment: Maybe re-install solves the problem

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem, just fyi. Certainly something buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Updating visual studio 2015 helped.